# C#: catch test failure during classcleanup

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is it possible to nest TestMethods in ClassCleanup and have them run/behave as TestMethods instead of regular method calls?

I have a TestClass to test an AppMngr class I created to manage a process.  I test for the ability to Open/Close the app (e.g. MyNotepadMngrClass.Open() and ...Close()).  I have several more classes that do work inside that process (e.g. MyNotepadWorkerClass.WriteLine() or ...DoSomething() ).  When testing the other classes I need to start notepad and close it when done.  ClassInitialize/ClassCleanup are obvious places for this.  But I want to *confirm* notepad closed.

So I created a static [TestMethod] for the Close operation.  I call it from ClassCleanup in MyNotepadWorkerTestClass.  It performs the close operation fine.  But if I add something like -- Assert.IsFalse(true); -- to the body of my close method the test run does not fail.

Let me know if what I am trying to do fundamentally wrong.  Appreciate any you can give help.

P.S. Hey TestStand guys, I am looking for Setup/Ceanup behaviour during RunSelectedStep.  TestDriven.NET gives me RunSelectedStep.  So how do I catch failures during ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup.

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question without some sourecode. "Assert.IsFalse(true);" will not make the test fail, if executed in a try...catch(Exception) block because failed assertions are propagated (at least in nunit) with AssertExceptions. If the AssertExceptions is caught with a catch(Exception) nunit will not get it.

Comment: Assume the simple case that throws no exceptions viz. where Assert.IsFalse(true)gareentees a failure like you would expect.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question on the TestStand side...
If you right-click a step in TestStand and use the "Run Selected Step" option, it will actually run all the steps in the Setup and Cleanup step groups as well...
Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: @JJ, in TS you can place TestSteps (or TestMethods in this case) in the setup and cleanup step groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassCleanup is by definition to be used "after all the tests in the test class have run" ([from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute%28VS.80%29.aspx)), so you probably can't add new test methods in there. You'll need to restructure your test.

Comment: Surely I am not the first that needs this.

Comment: That depends -- technically you're asking to be able to run tests after the tests have ended. If you mean specifically your Close at end of test method -- I'd just have a Close method in your test class that's called at the end of other test methods (without seeing code it's hard to say precisely), rather than in the ClassCleanup attributed method. You just have to be careful about what ClassCleanup means -- in the context of your tests specifically.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Maybe what i want is better achieved through test lists where I can have setup tests and cleanup tests at either end of the test list.  I will leave it unanswered in hopes of a more creative solution.